# Comma before "including"?

Tags: punctuation, commas, sentence, present-participles

Does this sentence require a comma before *including*?

> He has written on a range of moral issues *including* poverty, globalization, and euthanasia.

Comment: This is one of those hateful gerund clauses that is inherently ambiguous, so it always requires a comma and the understanding that it means _the items that follow the word **including** are just a few examples, not an exhaustive list_. If what you want is an exhaustive list, then instead of **including**, you must say either "a range of moral issues: poverty, globalization, and euthanasia" or "He has written on the moral issues of poverty, globalization, and euthanasia" -- "a range of" then becomes a pointless verbosity. Say what you mean and mean what you say. Don't use unnecessary words.

Comment: @BillFranke: I agree, especially about the comma and the non-definitivity/-ness, although I consider *including* a participle here.

Comment: @Cerberus: You may be right that it's a participle rather than a gerund, so I should change the term to _/-ing/-word clauses_. Then whatever its part of speech is has no bearing on its meaning or stylistic fitness.

Comment: @BillFranke: You could call them that, or *participial phrases*, or *-ing modifiers*? I like to distinguish between *-ing* forms that mean **"that/which/who include(s)"** and those meaning **"the act of including / to include"**, but I understand there are some who somehow prefer using one word for both *-ing* forms. [You could replace the *-ing* forms in my sentence with *that mean* and *to prefer*, respectively...see how nicely that works?]

Answer (score 8):

It requires a comma because *including* is the subordinating conjunction for the dependent clause. Notice that if you DON'T put a comma there, you are essentially qualifying the moral issues upon which he has written as only those that include poverty ("moral issues including poverty"), in which case "globalization, and euthanasia" becomes one of two things: either a meaningless fragment, or the last two elements in a linking sequence that was not intended ("1. a range of moral issues including poverty, 2. globalization, and 3. euthanasia").

Comment: +1 Agreed, but it is a participle, not a conjunction.

Comment: @Cerberus But just as with many parts of speech it can qualify as more than one part of speech, and although I can't absolutely swear to this, I think it _must_ qualify as the subordinating conjunction for the dependent clause in this case, because we have a dependent clause which is conjoined to the independent clause, and something conjoins it, and "including" is the word which conjoins it, so I don't think we can say that it _isn't_ the subordinating conjunction.

Comment: It could also be “a range of moral issues that include 1) poverty, 2) globalisation, and 3) euthanasia”, though I'll readily admit that I can think of no moral issues that include all these things. But it seems odd to me to refer to globalisation as a moral issue, anyway.

Comment: Setting aside the point that the debate over whether the use of "including" creates an ambiguity was neither invited by nor relevant to the question posed, I completely disagree that it creates an ambiguity. "Including" has a clear meaning, and the fact that some writers may use it sloppily or some readers may infer the possibility of a complete list should not dissuade any writer from using it properly.

Comment: @Cerberus There is set of *-ing* words that either already have or are on their way towards turning into prepositions.  I don’t think you’ll quibble over words like *during, barring, excepting, failing, saving, notwithstanding* as one-time verbal forms now accepted as prepositions. Others aren’t necessarily there yet, or have variant analyses where dictionaries hedge their bets with weasel words: even the OED calls *excluding, passing, pending* “quasi-prepositions”, and [other sources](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_prepositions) list some as “not fully grammaticized”.

Comment: @Cerberus (*in continuation*) On the other hand, Oxford Dictionaries Online has cut the *quasi* cord entirely and now lists [*including*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/including) and [*excluding*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/excluding) as full-fledged prepositions. I confess this leads to apparent contradictions which I don’t understand, since those types of words can themselves be followed by prepositional phrases of their own, and I am unused to PPs acting as NPs. [See this example](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/including#Preposition).

Comment: @tchrist: 1. I am prepared to quibble over those words that can at least theoretically be analysed as participles, including *during, failing, notwithstanding*, but not over your other examples, which do indeed demonstrate the phenomenon of participles-turned-prepositions (already noted by Fowler). 2. *Preposition+ preposition* is possible, so I don't think that should be an extremely strong test, though it can perhaps be an indication. *Up in the clouds, over at my friend's.*

Comment: @Cerberus I tend to view those as compound prepositions when they stack, so *up in* and *over at*.  I don’t find the *including during* example to work like those, though.

Comment: @tchrist: I don't know, I find it questionable. I would be reluctant to trust in it as a reliable test.

Answer (score 1):

In that sentence, a comma is required before “including,” which is introducing a partial list (per *Garner's Modern American Usage*).

@user21497, @Cerberus, @BillFranke, @John M. Landsberg: A participle (the *-ing* or *-ed* form of a verb) can be used in various ways: as a gerund, which is a noun (singing is fun); as an adjective (a flying nun; a missed opportunity); or, as is the case above, as a preposition. (Preposition = a word governing, and usually preceding, a noun or pronoun and expressing a relation to another word or element in the clause, as in “the man on the platform” and  “she arrived after dinner” -- from the online Oxford dictionary.)

Comment: Analysing certain *-ing* words as prepositions is an interesting topic. With some there is no question: “I sleep ***during* the day.”** But in others there may still be some leeway or dispute or transition. I have the feeling that *including* is one such, since when you say “I sleep all the time, ***including* during the day.’** you find that if you analyse *including* there as a preposition, then its prepositional object must be the entire prepositional phrase *during the day* — making it suddenly a noun phrase, which I’m more than a little skeptical about. See my comments to Cerberus above.

Comment: I would begin with "-ing and -ed forms can be used...", not "a participle can be used...", because participles exclude gerunds and prepositions.

Answer (score 1):

I think most of you are wrong.  It is not a gerund because it is not acting as a noun, nor is it a participle because it is not used as a describing word. It is also not a subordinating conjunction as this requires a complete sentence on both sides of the conjunction.  It is a transition word.

Comment: If you mean 'it's possibly somewhere in the verb - noun - adjective quagmire that ing-forms tend to inhabit' I'd agree. Quirk examines the noun - verb cline, but the adjectivy influence is usually present too. It could be read as a participle here. But this is not a direct answer to the question OP asks. You might like to look at the [“I left smoking”, “I quit smoking”, “I gave up smoking”, “I stopped smoking” are these same? thread](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/156759/i-left-smoking-i-quit-smoking-i-gave-up-smoking-i-stopped-smoking-are).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ah, but these are now held to be [prepositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_prepositions#Single_words), which is not even in your spectral gamut. So I think the poster is on to something here.

Comment: @tchrist Yes; I'm more convinced of the preposition-ness of 'including' and similar than that of those wotsits lacking noun groups. So 'transition' is being used to mean 'migrating from POS4 to POS12'. Different from 'hard to say it's POS4 rather than POS12, but whatever it is, it's been there a long time'.

Comment: I can see the answer here "It is a transition word" which carries the implication of "It needs a comma" but adding that explicitly would be good.