# What is the grammar structure? "I am not going to stand here watching you do it"?

Tags: gerunds, complements, predicative-complements

Is this sentence correct?

> I am not going to stand here watching you do it.

I saw it in an article. If it is - and I think it is - why is "watching" a gerund? What is the grammar structure? Is it a subject complement or something similar?

Comment: If you saw it in a published article and it was written by a native speaker, you are entitled to assume it's grammatical, even if looks like it violates some rule you've learned. So, yes, it is correct. As for why _watch_ is a gerund, that's because a subordinate clause like that coming after _stand_ has to be a gerund. You could also say _stand here and watch you do it_, which is just conjunction reduction and not a subordinate clause.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I will remember the skill!

Comment: **Watch** is not a gerund (as the term is usually understood). It is a participle, and the phrase "watching you do it" is an adverbial phrase modifying "stand [here]".

Comment: The difference between a gerund and a present participle in English is entirely theoretical. As is the categorization of _watching you do it_ as an adverbial phrase. I would say it's much more complex than that.

Comment: @ColinFine  Sorry for bothering you guys! As this kind of questions have confused me for a while. What you said "watching you do it" is an adverbial phrase modifying "stand [here]." Is the grammar complement? What key word should I use to search if I want to learn about the grammar?

Comment: [This](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/156759/i-left-smoking-i-quit-smoking-i-gave-up-smoking-i-stopped-smoking-are/156779#156779)  may help you.

Comment: I agree with Colin Fine's analysis.  Think what can go in the slot "stand here __": "watchfully (adv.)", "stupified (adj)".  If it were a gerund, we'd get NPs here, like *"a mouse" rather than :"quietly".

Comment: @Greg Lee But 'gerund' has conflicting definitions (and some reject the term completely).

Answer (score -1):

"Watching' here is a participle phrase. You could add 'while' before it and it would still be an adverbial of time. It cannot have a function of a nominal phrase, so not a gerund.