# "come crashing down" as an idiom

Tags: phrases, verbs, idioms

> [come crashing down](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/come%20crashing%20down):  to fall down with a lot of noise and force
>
> *The whole stack of cans came crashing down.*

According to M-Webster's come crashing down is an idiom. Otherwise, how is such a pharse analysed?

Seconldy, is **come down** used in the idiom *come crashing down*? Merriam-webster's doesn't include "*fall down*" as a meaning in its entry of  *come down*.

Comment: What is your question?  The meaning of the phrase is clear in the context of your example.  And it is used as a fairly obvious metaphor when referring to, say, the stock market or someone's mood.  It is an "idiom" only in the sense that it's fairly common and is often metaphorized.  "Come down" has a somewhat different meaning, and probably derives from someone being "brought down off a pedestal" or some such.

Comment: This is a construction that's much broader than one idiom. _Come down_ is already a phrasal verb (and links with _go down, get down, bring down_), and phrasal verbs are by definition idioms. Add the participle and you get a very common way to express an event - use a generic verb and a detailed participle. It's more common in some languages than others -- it's very common in Spanish -- but English uses it in narratives a lot. Take a look at the way the Harry Potter books describe events.

Answer (score 3):

[Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/come-down) gives the appropriate sense of what it labels the phrasal verb usage here:

> **come down** phrasal verb
>
> ...
>
> 3 to fall to the ground
>
> - A lot of trees came down in the storm.
> - We were still out in the fields when the rain started coming down.

I'd say that there is enough cohesion between 'come' and 'down' here to justify its being considered a multi-word verb:

- The trees *came down* in the storm.
- The trees *fell* [to the ground] in the storm.

In spite of the cohesion, it is possible to insert ing-forms between 'come' and 'down' to describe the manner and/or degree of the falling:

- The cans came crashing down.
- Jack and Jill came tumbling down.
- The rain came bucketing down.
- The ash keys came spiralling down.

Whether or not one considers *come V-ing down* as cohesive enough to also be considered multi-word verbs (of a different class) is open to debate. Certainly

- The ash keys spiralled to the ground (etc)

is available for

- The ash keys came spiralling down [to the ground].

The grammar is fairly idiosyncratic ('went V-ing up' is unusual), but these expressions are idiomatic (commonly used and accepted), so they arguably qualify as idioms.

One famous example of this usage, which has doubtless popularised it, is from the old spiritual/hymn:

> Joshua fought[/fit] the battle of Jericho ... Jericho ... Jericho;
>
> Joshua fought the battle of Jericho
>
> And the walls came tumbling down.

Comment: what about **he went haring past**?

Comment: Yes, and I think that's pretty productive (racing / dashing / hurtling / bowling / flying). But not totally (??crawling / ??walking / ??running / *bouncing) (with no complement, like _past the school_). It's idiosyncratic, with probably all prepositions-or-are-they.

Comment: to which one does "(with no complement, like past the school)." apply? Secondly , prepositions-or-are-they?

Comment: Adding a complement makes them all sound more natural. 'John came walking past' is less natural-sounding than 'John came walking past the bandstand'. 'John came walking by' works better. //  The semi-traditional view is that prepositiony things in multi-word verbs like 'He hung **up**' / 'He went **on** for ages' /  'He's passed **away**' / 'She's passed **out**' ... are best called '[verbal] particles'. The CGEL stance is that they should all be classed as prepositions, intransitive where there is no complement.

Answer (score 2):

I guess come crashing down can be used in another context to give a slightly different meaning. Like when you say a drug smuggling scheme "came crashing down", you are saying that 
1. It was large and extensive
2. It was destroyed very quickly, very suddenly, and had a great impact, like how the plans to build a multi-billion dollar fusion reactor "came crashing down" when they realised they were unable to build it.

It can literally fall down, or more metaphorically mean that it had a great impact when it was suddenly destroyed/unable to stand.

Answer (score 1):

> "The whole stack of cans came crashing down." According to M-Webster's come crashing down is an idiom.

It is not an idiom. It is perfectly understandable as it is. It is an ordinary use. "came crashing down" seems to be "verb - participle - adverb," with the {participle adverb} being the complement of "came."

> Otherwise, how is such a phrase analysed?

The OED describes it thus:

> **Come (v.) 4 b. Followed by a present participle or gerund indicating a concomitant action or activity (often expressing the method or manner of movement).**
>
> intransitive.
>
> 1916   H. L. Wilson Somewhere in Red Gap iii. 113   *So I yelled out back to an old hick of a gardener..and he comes running.*
>
> 1921   S. Colvin Memories & Notes xvii. 295   *The whole weight of the Atlantic comes crashing against the granite juts and buttresses.*
>
> 2007   Atlantic Monthly Dec. 84/2   *Another of our members..came clutching a bag full of peacock-blue, pea-sized beans.*

Comment: No; there's a difference between the 'go fishing / come shopping' phase-structure _V + ing-form_, and other _V + ing-form_ constructions – and the _come & ing-form & down_ construction. The particle is mandatory in the 'come crashing / tumbling / hurtling spiralling / bucketing down', but not in the verbs-in-phase structure (He'll come shopping). 'Come crashing against' is a transitive analogue of 'come V-ing down'. 'Come clutching a bag of goodies' is, of course, come + past-participial clause. A totally different construction. // An idiom may be an odd/rarish grammatical construct.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: "*The particle is mandatory in the 'come crashing / tumbling / hurtling spiralling / bucketing down*', I would be interested to see authority for that statement. The participle is an adverb or part of an adverbial phrase and may be omitted or replaced: "The whole weight of the Atlantic comes *powerfully* against the granite juts." / The whole weight of the Atlantic comes  against the granite juts.--"[He] came {clutching a bag of beans} - adverbial complement or free modifier.

Comment: He came crashing? She came spiralling? There can be other licensing particles, such as 'into' [the room], but the come + Ving. formula doesn't work for these verbs. Note that 'She came shopping.' is a different ('look-alike') construction. V + ing-form constructions have been dealt with in previous threads.

Comment: You seem to have said that the participle is mandatory, and then given the example of the participle being wrong. "He came crashing? She came spiralling?" I'm a little confused.

Comment: It needs to be 'He came crashing down.': 'down' (or perhaps 'in') is necessary. 'He came crashing.' is unacceptable. This is not the 'go shopping' / 'start walking' phase structure described (along with various  other V + -ing form constructions) [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/156759/i-left-smoking-i-quit-smoking-i-gave-up-smoking-i-stopped-smoking-are/156779#156779).

Comment: The OED explanation is given above. It is not incorrect and it describes, for the OP, the nature of “come + “ing form”.

Comment: Please check elsewhere on ELU for the wisdom of using dictionaries (even the best) as an adequate authority for pronouncing on grammar. This too has been discussed here before.

Comment: I have done and, in this case, I'm content. ;)